# How to implement server sent an event in spring boot webFlux for a particular user

Tags: spring-boot

How to implement server sent an event in spring boot webFlux for a particular user
For example:- I need to send the event as per user not for broadcast

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [`EmitterProcessor`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/EmitterProcessor.html) to add new values to the `Flux`. For example:

```java
 public class Event {
     private String destination;
     private String value;

     // Getters + Setters
 }
```

And then you can have a shared `EmitterProcessor`:

```java
private EmitterProcessor<Event> events = EmitterProcessor.create();
```

Now you can use a controller to subscribe to it:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/{destination}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> getEvents(@PathVariable String destination) {
    return events.share()
        .filter(event -> event.getDestination().equals(destination))
        .map(Event::getValue);
}
```

This will create a shared instance of the `EmitterProcessor` and filter so that only values matching the given destination will arrive.

Now you can use the following code somewhere else to send an event to a specific user (or a destination in this case):

```java
events.onNext(new Event(destination, "Hello world!!"));
```

Comment: events.onNext(new Event(destination, "Hello world!!")); This code is work for broadcasting not for specefic user

Comment: @Varunkumar Can you explain what you mean? If you make `destination` into a user-specific variable, and the user calls the endpoint using the same `destination`, then only he will see the given event. This works, because the `filter()` statement will filter out everything except the messages for a given `destination`, and thus, for a specific user.

Comment: Based on the above implementation, Server-sent event is work for a user but I event will send multiple time, I need to remove event, and I also need to store Server-sent event connection, Please Share me one demo project